# SQL Server Plan Guide vs Plan Freezing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am bit confused with terminology as official Microsoft SQL Server documentation including [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx) refers to plan guide the one you create using sp_create_plan_guide proc. Does plan freezing is same thing or slightly different?. Reading Erland's great article [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#factgathering)

> There are two ways to set up plan guides, a general way, and a
>   shortcut which is also known as plan freezing. General plan guides
>   were introduced in SQL 2005, whereas plan freezing was added in SQL
>   2008.

I am reading plan freezing is when you create guide using [sp_create_plan_guide_from_handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964726.aspx)

Seeking a clarification on terminology being used, does plan guide and plan freezing is the same thing or they refer to slightly different way to stick the execution plan in the cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is my understanding as well, and this post helps provide some examples for you to review.

[Plan guides (plan freezing) in SQL Server 2005/2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916034714/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/02/19/plan-guides-plan-freezing-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx)